# convert GPS coordinates to C-SQUARES at any resolution

Tags: geospatial, julia

a C-Squares encoder in Julia.

FYI, C-Squares is a geocoding algorithm that assigns GPS coordinates to a spatial grid with a chosen resolution. Its specifications is here: https://www.cmar.csiro.au/csquares/spec1-1.htm

intended usage:

```julia
# random coordinates
LATITUDES  = 180 .* rand(50) .- 90
LONGITUDES = 360 .* rand(50) .- 180
identify_csquares.(LATITUDES, LONGITUDES; resolution=.01)
```

source code:

```julia
""""
inputs:
- latitude, longitude: in decimal and CRS = WGS84
- resolution: decimal degrees according to the WGS84 datum, must be a number from the sequence 10, 5, 1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.05, etc.

output: C-SQUARES notation
"""
function identify_csquares(latitude::T, longitude::T; resolution::T)::String where {T<:Real}
    k = _encode_resolution(resolution)
    # resolution=10 ⇒ k=0, resol=5 ⇒ k=1, resol=1 ⇒ k=2, resol=.5 ⇒ k=3, resol=.1 ⇒ k=4, resol=.01 ⇒ k=5, etc.

    if k == -1 error("resolution must be a number from the sequence 10, 5, 1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.05, etc.") end
    if latitude ≤ -90 || latitude ≥ 90 || longitude ≤ -180 || longitude ≥ 180 error("invalid GPS coordinates") end

    res = _identify_quadrant(latitude, longitude; sub_quadrant=false)
    ϕ_rem = abs(latitude)  # rem = remainder
    λ_rem = abs(longitude)

    ϕ_digit = Int(ϕ_rem ÷ 10)  # from 0 to 8
    λ_digit = Int(λ_rem ÷ 10)  # from 0 to 17
    ϕ_rem -= 10 * ϕ_digit
    λ_rem -= 10 * λ_digit
    res *= string(ϕ_digit) * lpad(λ_digit, 2, '0')
    if k == 0 return res end

    for i ∈ 1:k
        a, b = divrem(i, 2)
        if Bool(b)  # resolution 5, 0.5, 0.05, etc.
            res *= ":" * _identify_quadrant(ϕ_rem, λ_rem)
        else  # resolution 1, 0.1, 0.01, etc.
            tmp = 10^a  # 10^(1-a) throw error: negative power must be float
            ϕ_digit = Int(ϕ_rem * tmp ÷ 10)  # from 0 to 9
            λ_digit = Int(λ_rem * tmp ÷ 10)  # from 0 to 9
            ϕ_rem -= 10 * ϕ_digit / tmp
            λ_rem -= 10 * λ_digit / tmp
            res *= string(ϕ_digit) * string(λ_digit)
        end
    end
    return res
end


""""ϕ = latitude, λ = longitude"""
function _identify_quadrant(ϕ::T, λ::T; sub_quadrant::Bool=true)::String where {T<:Real}
    if sub_quadrant  # both ϕ & λ ∈ 0:9
            if λ < 5 && ϕ ≥ 5 return "3"  # north west
        elseif λ ≥ 5 && ϕ ≥ 5 return "4"  # north east
        elseif λ ≥ 5 && ϕ < 5 return "2"  # south east
        elseif λ < 5 && ϕ < 5 return "1"  # south west
        else error("oh no")
        end
    else  # ϕ ∈ -8:8 & λ ∈ -17:17
            if λ < 0 && ϕ ≥ 0 return "7"  # north west
        elseif λ ≥ 0 && ϕ ≥ 0 return "1"  # north east
        elseif λ ≥ 0 && ϕ < 0 return "3"  # south east
        elseif λ < 0 && ϕ < 0 return "5"  # south west
        else error("oh no")
        end
    end
end


"""
let (uₖ) be the sequence u₀=10, u₁=5, u₂=1, u₃=.5, u₄=.1, u₅=.05, etc.

explicit expression of (uₖ) given by:
uₖ = 10/10ⁿ if k=2n   (k even)
uₖ =  5/10ⁿ if k=2n+1 (k odd)

this julia function returns the value of k
- input: resolution of C-SQUARES in decimal degree
- output: index k so that uₖ=input, -1 if invalid input
"""
function _encode_resolution(degree::T)::Int where {T<:Real}
    if degree < 0 || degree > 10 return -1 end

    x = log10(degree)  # uₖ = 10/10ⁿ if k=2n; let x=log10(uₖ) ⇒ x=1-n
    try
        return 2 * (1 - Int(x))  # n=1-x ⇒ return k=2n
    catch e  # Int(x) throw InexactError if decimal part isn’t approx 0
        if !isa(e, InexactError) throw(e) end
    end

    x -= log10(5)  # uₖ = 5/10ⁿ if k=2n+1; let x=log10(uₖ)-log10(5) ⇒ x=-n
    try
        return 1 - 2 * Int(x)  # n=-x ⇒ return k=2n+1
    catch e
        if !isa(e, InexactError) throw(e) end
    end

    return -1
end
```

my code cannot handle some edge cases (see section 9.3 & 9.4 in the specifications) because of rounding error.